# MySQL query giving duplicate entry error 1062

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1062

Why is this query giving an error? The error is: SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
INSERT INTO `static_number_source` (`IDString`, `source`) VALUES
('RUS-001A', 'Thub'), #one
('RUS-001A', 'Fort'), #two
('RUS-002A', 'Thub'), #three
('RUS-002A', 'Fort'), #four
('RUS-003A', 'Thub'), #five
('RUS-003A', 'Fort'), #six
('RUS-004A', 'Thub'), #seven
('RUS-004A', 'Fort'); #eight
```

Comment: What does the table schema look like?

Comment: ID, IDString, source. ID is the primary key. ID and source need to be unique, but IDString can be non-unique.

Comment: Not just the column names, what I was interested in is if ID had a default value or has `AUTO_INCREMENT`...

Comment: ID should be AUTO_INCREMENT... I'm working in a database made by someone else. How can I figure that out for sure? I'm using HeidiSQL.

Comment: use `show create table static_number_source`

Comment: CREATE TABLE `static_number_source` (
    `ID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `IDString` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `source` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either Alter the table to add AUTO_INCREMENT TO THE ID field, or always provide an Id on Inserts

For adding `AUTO_INCREMENT` just find the largest value of id in the table and set id it to one more.

Answer (score 1):

IDString seem to be set as PRIMARY. PRIMARY must have unique value. If you want to use multiple value with the same value, use a regular non-unique INDEX.

By the way, if you have a UNIQUE index on both field, thoses are similar :

```
('RUS-002A', 'Fort'), #three
('RUS-002A', 'Fort'), #four
```

Comment: I have other entries in that table for the IDString column that aren't unique. For the example of #three and #four, they aren't actually the same in my real query. I just messed up when I changed the values for my post. I edited my first post.

Comment: @KebinKeeler Ok then you need to remove the PRIMARY key on `IDString` and use a regular INDEX non-unique : `ALTER TABLE  static_number_source ADD INDEX (  IDString )`

Comment: The table structure has 3 columns. ID, IDString, source. ID is the primary key.

Comment: The IDString field can already accept non-unique entries. There are sometimes 4 entries that are the same, just as long as the primary key and source are different.