# Why does phpmyadmin give me the error #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the error #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' after running the query:

```
 INSERT
 INTO
`categories`(
`id`,
`forum_id`,
`title`,
`description`
)

 VALUES(
 1,
 1,
'General Discussions',
'General web/wapmasters discussions forum.')
```

and the part that gave me an error was:

```
 VALUES(
  1,
  1,
'General Discussions',
'General web/wapmasters discussions forum.')
```

what is the reason for the error?

Comment: Because your table already has a row where the primary key has a value of '1'.  The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: [I would check out this article that seems to answer a very similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367532/mysql-query-giving-duplicate-entry-error-1062) Hope this helps :)

Comment: Gordon Linoff, what should i do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not Gordon, but stop trying to insert a value into an IDENTITY or AUTOINCREMENT column. Remove the  ID column from the column list, and the value you're trying to assign to it from the VALUES list.